# Finding the end coordinates of line

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I know $x_1 = 4$ and $y_1 = 3. $ Given the angle of $30$, how would I find the end coordinates of a line with the length of 5?

[The ending coords aren't correct. They are just there to show what I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVF3h.jpg)

Comment: I've tried turning the angle to radians then finding the end point's x value by doing X1 + sin(angle in radians) * distance, and doing the same with Y except using cos instead

Comment: Can you draw a picture and post it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should state the unit of your angle. Most commonly, an angle of "$30$" refers to degree measure, but this should be explicitly stated. Your sketch shows a degree symbol, but you've mentioned radians in your own comment under your question.

Anyway, assuming that the angle is in degree measure,

Consider the displacements from the initial point in horizontal and vertical axes separately.

Horizontal: $\displaystyle 5\cos 30^{\circ} = \frac{5\sqrt 3}{2}$

Vertical:  $\displaystyle 5\sin 30^{\circ} = \frac{5}{2}$

Add those to the initial coordinates to get the final coordinates as:

$$x_2 = 4 + \frac{5\sqrt 3}{2} = \frac{8 + 5\sqrt 3}2, y_2 = 3 + \frac{5}{2} = \frac {11}2$$

Comment: I wasn't sure about the radians thing, I remember someone told me to convert the degrees to radians to do this.

Comment: @hsel *In general* - bearing in mind that generalisations can be dangerous, but *in general*, anyway, you don't "need" to work in radian measure except if you're doing some types of calculus problems. For more elementary problems, either measure works just as well - but you need to be very clear about which you're using before computing trigonometric ratios. Also note that some formulae (usually pertaining to circular sector/segment areas and arc lengths) can be quite different between the two measures.